# How to add Puspin in PDF file with Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are integrating Autodesk Forge Viewer's for our application and like in BIM 360 we need to use pushpin for evenement localisation.

Unfortunally we can't use the BIM 360 Pushpin extension because we dont have any BIM 360 license.

We found an example for 3D plan and integrated it with success: 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg

We don't have any solutions for PDF/DWG files.

We have try to update the 3D pushpin sample but when we move the screen that not work. The pushpin don't move.

Is somebody can hel us for solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59374704/4838205) could help, just need to adjust it to the specific location (as the approach of reading the location via `dbId` would not work for 2D).