# Loading IconMarkupExtension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Trying to add labels with text on top of the objects in 3D viewer. I found the following post about an extension that does this:

[image: Label extension]

https://twitter.com/augustomaia/status/1205652823733460993

```
viewer.loadExtension('IconMarkupExtension', {
  icons: [
    { dbId: 987,label: '300C',css:'fas fa-thermometer' }
  ]
});
```

Loading this extension, produces the following error:

"Extension not found: IconMarkupExtension. Has it been registered?"

Is this part of the official Extensions? Or is there similar functionality available in some code example how to make extension like this that would add the text label on top of the object with dbid and label?

Comment: This extension is probally made by Augusto himself and registered locally, i cannot find an extension by this name in the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/). Every extensions that you want to load into the viewer has to be registered first, thats why you're getting the `Extension not found: IconMarkupExtension. Has it been registered?` error. The extension simply doesnt exists in the current context. If you're interested in writing your own extensions i can refer you to [this](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/extensions) tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a custom extension, still a work in progress, but you can check at [this repo](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/js/iconExtension.js).

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in looking at some the example (specially the markup one) provided by Denis Gregor here:
https://github.com/apprentice3d/ForgeViewerExtensions